# JUnit 5 and Surefire Report NoClassDefFound NamespacedHierarchicalStore

Tags: junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

Running tests with the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

With Maven Plugin Configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

When running it produces a maven build error of the following:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s <<< FAILURE! -- in JUnit Jupiter
[ERROR] JUnit Jupiter.JUnit Jupiter -- Time elapsed: 0 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/store/NamespacedHierarchicalStore$CloseAction
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.AbstractExtensionContext.<clinit>(AbstractExtensionContext.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor.prepare(JupiterEngineDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor.prepare(JupiterEngineDescriptor.java:31)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$CloseAction
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 27 more
```

The errors started with maven-surefire-plugin version `3.2.1` and `3.2.2`.  Using previous version of `3.1.2` there is no issue and everything is good.

Comment: @BarbetNL - I did find a work around as it was to remove the JUnit dependency from the SureFire plugin configuration.  I was hoping for a better solution, however, things have been working properly with removing the dependency.

Comment: That disables the junit 4 tests right? Unfortunately we need to keep supporting ju4 & ju5. Have you tried with junit-vintage-engine dependecy, would that work?

Comment: I am not sure, we are only using JUnit 5 so it didn't impact my tests.